# Automatic capture (Raster to Vector) using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vectorization

I would like to know the automatic process for Scanned hand drawn line Raster to vector conversion.

Comment: The question in it's current state is too broad. Please provide more information about your situation to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 1):

within arcgis, you first need to [reclassify](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000sr000000) your image in 2 classes (1 for lines and 0 for bacground), then you can use "[raster to polyline](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000009000000)". If needed, you can clean up bit using the "[thin](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000003n000000)" command that will reduce your raster lines to a single pixel width.

Note that there is also an ArcGIS extension called [arcscan](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000w00000001000000) for more advanced conversions. here is a [tutorial](http://downloads.esri.com/support/documentation/other_/1035ArcScan_for_ArcGIS_Tutorial.pdf) for arscan

Comment: Thanks..I have tried using arcscan but it was not enable vectorization tool and I am using single band image.

Comment: for the vectorization tool, you need to start an edit session with a line. Single band image is OK, but you have to use a "classified" renderer with two classes.